# How to load hidden div based on saved radio button selection using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that the user can save and return to edit.  I have an area on the form that toggles a div based on the user's answer to a previous question.  If the answer is 'yes', the div should display.  However, if the user returns to the form, and 'yes' is selected, the div remains hidden.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BbrwT/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Select:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="toggle" value="1" checked="checked">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="toggle" value="0">No
</div>

<div id="details">
   Details
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#details').hide();

    $('.toggle').on('change',function(){

        var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;

        $(this).parent().next('#details').toggle(showOrHide);

    })    

})
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here?  By default your having yes checked so you need to deselect it and select it again for the div to show but it appears to work fine...  I guess the real question is how is the user returning to to the form?  If its through a back button then you'll probably need to invoke the change event manually on page load via `$('.toggle').change();`.  If its through just coming back to the page then you have the prev value saved somewhere and thus should check if it yes and if so again invoke the change manually on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're explicitly hiding the details div on `document.ready`

Check the value of the radiobutton first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($('.toggle:checked').val() != 1)
        $('#details').hide();

    ...

})
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works if the radio is selected (http://jsfiddle.net/BbrwT/6/), but how about if the question hasn't been answered yet (http://jsfiddle.net/BbrwT/7/)?  The div should be hidden if this is the case.

Comment: Now if the answer is selected onload, the div does not display.  http://jsfiddle.net/BbrwT/10/

Comment: @Michael, sorry. Try that. The selector `.toggle` wasn't working like I thought it would, so here is another option.

Comment: Great.  My only problem is that I have multiple radios on the form, and was toggling based on class.  Is there no way to do it with the .toggle selector?

Comment: Replace the selector with `.toggle` again.

Comment: This no longer works if I have multiple radio buttons on the same page?  Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/BbrwT/14/

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to say, I made a version that works better with less code:

```
// Make sure the page is loaded before doing anything
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Makes sure that it shows the div correctly, and doesn't flip the effects
    if($('.toggle:checked').val() !== 1)
        // Hides the div
        $('#details').hide();

    // When there is a change in the selection
    $('.toggle').on('change', function() {
        // Hide or show the div, depending on the var showOrHide
        $(this).parent().next('#details').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

It's also well documented. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BbrwT/5/**

I condensed your code a little:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#details').hide();

    $('.toggle').on('change',function(){
        $('#details').toggle($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

I changed your HTML a bit too (removed the `checked="checked"` from the first element and added it to the second instead).